# Javascript function stops executing when another interaction occurs

Tags: javascript, html

In my code example below I have two buttons that do the following:

1) Clicking button 1 executes a while loop

2) Clicking button 2 executes a log statement

If you click button 1 and then click button 2, button 1 stops executing.

Is it possible to have button 1 continue to execute when another action occurs?

```js
function buttonOneClick() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 1000) {
    console.log('index is ', i);
    i++;
  }
}

function buttonTwoClick() {
  console.log('button two clicked');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="buttonOneClick()">Click Button One and Start Loop</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonTwoClick()">Click Button Two</button>
```

Comment: I do not see the behavior you describe, but the answer is "no"; JavaScript is single-threaded. The code in the button 1 handler will keep running through all 1000 iterations before the browser will respond to a  click on the other button.

Comment: I doubt your actual code depends on console.log calls. What's the actual problem code?

Comment: @Pointy If you run the code snippet and click button one you should see the index begin to log. If you click button 2 you'll see the index stops being logged and 'button two clicked' is logged.

Comment: I did do that, and it did not work that way for me (Firefox). If you're seeing that in Chrome, it's because the `console` mechanism in Chrome is weird.

Comment: @ziggywiggy You are correct - The actual problem is in React Native. When a user takes a picture and clicks the back button I want to display a saving screen, however the image save is then interrupted and is never able to finish.

Comment: @Pointy yes, I'm seeing it in Chrome.

Comment: So if I understand, you're wondering why code halts when the user navigates away from the page?

Comment: @ziggywiggy Kind of - They aren't actually navigating away yet since I handle the back press and basically just want to show/hide content until the image is saved and then navigate back.

Comment: Please define a concrete problem in your actual question, not the comments.  There are certainly ways to do things simultaneously in JavaScript even though it is a single threaded language, WebWorkers spring to mind immediately.  But without context of your **actual** use case, we might be suggesting that you over-engineer.  If you just want a timer to count up every second, WebWorkers are overkill since `setTimeout/Interval` would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for "JavaScript multi-threading": you could use webworkers for the problem. Put the code you want to execute in a **webworker**, that runs in the background (by definition):

> Web Workers is a simple means for web content to run scripts in
>   background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without
>   interfering with the user interface. In addition, they can perform I/O
>   using XMLHttpRequest (although the responseXML and channel attributes
>   are always null). Once created, a worker can send messages to the
>   JavaScript code that created it by posting messages to an event
>   handler specified by that code (and vice versa).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

With this solution you can have your function continuously executed, and still have access to other functions.

Note that this is not a traditional webworker in my solution, but an **inline webworker**.

```js
function buttonOneClick() {
  // create an inline webworker
  var blob = new Blob([
    document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent
  ], {
    type: "text/javascript"
  })

  // Note: window.webkitURL.createObjectURL() in Chrome 10+.
  var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Received: " + e.data);
  }
  worker.postMessage("hello"); // Start the worker.
}

function buttonTwoClick() {
  console.log('button two clicked');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="buttonOneClick()">Click Button One and Start Loop</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonTwoClick()">Click Button Two</button>

<script id="worker1" type="javascript/worker">
  // This script won't be parsed by JS engines because its type is javascript/worker.
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      self.postMessage( 'message from worker ' + i)
    }
  };
// Rest of your worker code goes here.
</script>
```

To check the results, use the real console, and scroll back a some - you'll find your `buttonTwoClick()` `console.log()`.

**One note, though**

Don't press **Tidy** in the snippet - it will mess up the worker, as it cannot "understand" what that is.